# closing of matplotlib.pyplot closes parent window also

Tags: python, matplotlib, pygtk

I am a beginner with matplotlib. I am trying to generate bar chart on click of a button, which is working as expected. The problem is, I dont want the parent window i.e the window with "Hello World" button to be closed when I close the pyplot i.e bar chart window.
I want only the pyplot to be closed when I click "x" on it.

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class HelloWorld:

 def __init__(self):
    self.a=[10,20,30,25]
    self.b=[12,2,30,14]
    self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    self.window.connect("destroy", self.destroy)
    self.window.set_border_width(10)
    self.button = gtk.Button("Hello World")
    self.button.connect("clicked", self.hello, None)
    self.window.add(self.button)
    self.button.show()
    self.window.show()

 def hello(self, widget, data=None):
    y_pos = np.arange(len(self.a))  
    error = np.random.rand(len(self.a))
    plt.barh(y_pos, self.b, xerr=error, align='center', alpha=0.4)
    plt.yticks(y_pos, self.a)
    plt.xlabel('Players')
    plt.title('Fastest Player')
    plt.show()


 def destroy(self, widget, data=None):
    gtk.main_quit()


 def main(self):
    gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
 hello = HelloWorld()
 hello.main()
```

Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: I tried it out and it works correctly here.

Comment: I tried too and it works correctly on Linux, Python 2.7

Comment: Yes, The chart is displayed. But when I close the chart window, I want the parent i.e main window with button to be still open.

Comment: I hope my question is clear. If I close the chart pyplot,only that pyplot window should be closed and not the 1st/main window.

Comment: SOLVED. In the matplotlib/examples directory, check out
user_interfaces/embedding_in_gtk2.py.

Comment: @rkatkam - Please take the time to provide some detail of how you solved this in an answer. Answering your own question is perfectly legitimate, and will help others who have a similar issue in the future. Thanks!