# Closing of matplotlib.pyplot also closes parent window Gtk3

Tags: python, matplotlib, gtk

I'm trying to solve the same problem as [another post from 6 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23804957/closing-of-matplotlib-pyplot-closes-parent-window-also?newreg=b19278dae65c4c6a9edd7f74c11089e2) but the example code that was used to solve the problem is no longer available and I can't comment on it to ask for an updated solution.

The example code below is taken from the original post with minor modifications to use the Gtk3 library that I'm using (I think the old one that was in the snippet is deprecated). It exhibits the same problem that I'm having where when I close Figure 1 it also closes the main Gtk window with the "Hello World" button on it. I only want it to close the Figure.

Thanks, and sorry if this isn't the right way to ask this question.

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class HelloWorld:

 def __init__(self):
    self.a=[10,20,30,25]
    self.b=[12,2,30,14]
    self.window = Gtk.Window()
    self.window.connect("destroy", self.destroy)
    self.window.set_border_width(10)
    self.button = Gtk.Button(label="Hello World")
    self.button.connect("clicked", self.hello, None)
    self.window.add(self.button)
    self.button.show()
    self.window.show()

 def hello(self, widget, data=None):
    y_pos = np.arange(len(self.a))  
    error = np.random.rand(len(self.a))
    plt.barh(y_pos, self.b, xerr=error, align='center', alpha=0.4)
    plt.yticks(y_pos, self.a)
    plt.xlabel('Players')
    plt.title('Fastest Player')
    plt.show()


 def destroy(self, widget, data=None):
    Gtk.main_quit()


 def main(self):
    Gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
 hello = HelloWorld()
 hello.main()
```

Comment: This code works perfectly fine for me (`matplotlib` version 3.4.3, Ubuntu 20.04). What is your `matplotlib` version number?